# Why don't changes to my podman image overwrite the current image in quay?

Tags: dockerfile, docker-image, podman, docker-build, quay.io

So I have an image I build locally i.e.

podman build -t quay.io/user/test-program:v2.0-x86_64

My image includes a step which copies the source code and later compiles it to build the binaries.

I pushed the initial image to quay with:

podman push quay.io/user/test-program:v2.0-x86_64

Afterwards, I made changes to the code and built the image again with:

podman build -t quay.io/user/test-program:v2.0-x86_64

However, when I push the image and pull it on another machine, the newest changes are not present. If I push the image with a different tag however, it seems like the changes are present.

Why is this? Do I need to remove / overwrite the existing quay image if the tag is exactly the same?

Comment: I suspect that the push worked but the pull didn't pull the updated image because there was a local copy with the same image name and tag. This is a source of frequent confusion. It's good practice to change the tag if the image changes. You can rm|untag the image before pulling to ensure you don't use the cached copy.

Comment: Is this true for the 'latest' tag as well? This seems rather counter-intuitive that pulling the latest from an external registry may not mean getting the latest on your local machine

Comment: Correct. It's misleading but there's some logic. If you build `foo:bar` locally and then immediately (inadvertently) `pull foo:bar`, should the local copy be overwritten with the older image? Container image tags are just labels. That it's called `latest` is confusing because it's the default tag and incorrect. It's best to use image digests (`@sha256:...`) but commonly SemVer is used although this requires retagging e.g. `1.20` when `1.20.2` replaces `1.20.1`.